# Android Studio - Android SDK not showing old apis (like Jelly bean)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have installed Android Studio and then Android-SDK but I can't find old APIS likes Jelly Bean. I have already try check and uncheck "show check buttons"

[image]

This is what I get when I reload SDK.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally go through cmd (yes I'm in windows) and open SDK Manager.exe as administrator. That let me download old apis and Extras like Google USB Driver.

Answer (score 0):

This means your ide is not able to connect with dl.google.com (sdk repository) .

Make sure you are connected to internet and site is not being blocked by firewall if there is any.
Also make sure to configure proxy in your sdk manager if you are using any.

Comment: Im not using a proxy plus I'm sure I have internet available.

Comment: try restarting your pc ;)